# Tomcat web application to communicate with other external deployed tomcat web applications

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

I have several web applications that are deployed as .war files on a Tomcat server.  Each web application has an ApplicationListener.java class which implements ServletContextListener. Within the ApplicationListener.java classes, I use ScheduledExecutorService to spawn a single thread which is used to consume messages from a queue:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

    ReferenceData.init();

    scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduledConsumer(), 0, ReferenceData.CONSUME_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

Here is my question:  Is it possible to create an additional web application that can "talk" with all of the others? I essentially want to create a dashboard that will let me display the current `ReferenceData.CONSUME_INTERVAL` values (used in the code above) for each web application, as well as the ability to update their values.

Is this possible? I would appreciate any design recommendations, details, or examples.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could *integrate* all your applications using an external place to store the messages to exchange between them. Saying this, you could use JSM or a database table.

Comment: All of the applications are currently consuming messages from different queues on an AMQP server. The ReferenceData.init(); call will load the CONSUME_INTERVAL from a properties file and provide static access via ReferenceData.java. So I'm looking to access the ReferenceData class of each application from one single place. Are you recommending to load the properties from a shared database rather than from individual property files?

Comment: Yes, in this case, it would be better to have all this data in a database, note that this is one possible solution and it would be better for you to evaluate if it's the best for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of configuration, right?

Well you could create one JMX-Beans in each of your application(slave), and a new Application that proxy all those JMX-Beans(master). Those JMX-Slaves register/unregister themselves to JMX-Master.

Now you got some Points:

- implemented User-Interfaces in the Manager-App of tomcat.
- implemented security-roles.
- implemented persistence of JMX-Master-Configuration.

(The JMX-Master may be solved in a one-class-app)

Comment: I've never really used JMX before but, after some initial reading, it seems like a perfect solution to try out. Thanks!